# How to analyze the logfile in "msiexec.exe /i your.msi /L*v c:\logfile.txt" inorder to fix error code 2869

Tags: visual-studio-2005, installation, setup-deployment, windows-installer

I have an application with version no: 1.0.1, which is an upgrade to the older version 1.0.0.

When I try to install the new version 1.0.1, when my system already has the older version 1.0.0 installed, I am getting the error 2869.

But if I uninstall the older version manually & than try to install the newer version, then it installs successfuly. 
It dawned on me that this error is due to some exception in custom action. And hence I executed the following command

```
msiexec.exe /i my.msi /L*v c:\logfile.txt
```

I dont know how to analyze this verbose log file, to find a fix for my problem.

What exact thing should I have a look at, so that I can get rid of that error code 2869.
 I am using VS2005 in WIN 7 machine.

Plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these articles will help you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc535232.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx

You can also post the log somewhere and link it in your post so we can take a look.

Basically, you should search for any custom action which has "Return Value 3". That custom action encounters a problem and stops the installation with an error.

Please use the same thread for updates on a problem instead of starting a different thread for each related question.